# CI_Session creating two session_id when logging in

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm facing a strange issue here, while trying to initialize a code igniter project for a friend.

I have a controller `user` with two functions : `login` and `dashboard`

The `login` function :

```
function login()
{
    if ($this->user_model->isLoggedIn())
        redirect('user', 'refresh');
    else 
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Login', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        if (!$this->form_validation->run())
            $this->load->view('login');
        else 
        {
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $validCredentials = $this->user_model->validCredentials($username, $password);
            if ($validCredentials)
                redirect('user/dashboard', 'refresh');
            else 
            {
                $data['error_credentials'] = 'Wrong Username/Password';
            $this->load->view('login', $data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `dashboard` function :

```
function dashboard()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['test'] = $this->session->all_userdata();
    if($this->user_model->isLoggedIn())
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
    else
        $this->load->view('sashboardnon', $data);
}
```

On the login view, there is a form poiting the `login` function, and when I log in, with good credentials, i'm redirected to the sashboardnon view, which is not what i'm expecting.

Here is my user_model.php :

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    function User_model()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    function validCredentials($username, $password)
    {
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $password = $this->encrypt->sha1($password);

        $req = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
        $data = array($username, $password);
        $req = $this->db->query($req, $data);
        if ($req->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $res = $req->result();
            $session_data = array(
                'username' => $res[0]->username,
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    function isLoggedIn()
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
    }

}
```

When I look in the ci_sessions table in my database, I see that there are two new entries when I click on the log-in button. One with the userdata I just added from my user_model, and another without it.

The problem is that the values in the userdata are erased when the second entry in the db is created. So I can't login.

Do someone know where the issue could come from ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you treat it as an "issue"? Most likely it is just a protection against session fixation/hijacking

Comment: Because the first entry in the db correctly has my new userdata, but not the second.

Comment: It is not clear from your question and the comment above: does logging in work or not?

Comment: And the problem is that, I stored a `logged_in` value in the session userdata, and it disappears when the second entry in the db is created. So i simply can't log in. Sorry i wasn't clear in the question, i'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think above code is a quite logical inconsistent and you should correct it. You have to move the logic from the Model to the Controller. Also, put the sessions management in the Controller and try to use the Model only for interacting with the Database.

(1) The model

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function User_model()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get($params) 
    {
        if(isset($params)) {

            $this->db->where("username", $params['username']);
            $this->db->where("password", $params['password']);
            $query = $this->db->get(users);

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
               return $query->result();
            }
        }
        return false;  
    }

}
```

(2) The Controller

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("users_model", "user");
    }

    function isLogdedIn() 
    {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function login() 
    {
        if ($this->isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect('user', 'refresh');
        }
        else {
            // show login form and put the logic here
        }        
    }



    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
    }

    function validateCredentials($username, $password) 
    {
        $params = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);
        $result = $this->user->get($params);

        if($result !== false) {
             return true;
        }
        return false;

    {


}
```

I hope the above example will help you to improve your code ;)

Comment: Thank you for this tip ! I'll edit my post to show the new code. But my problem remains the same : the session where I store my userdata is skipped to another one, and I can't use the userdata at all :(

Comment: In fact, I tried to set the $config['sess_use_database'] to FALSE to see the behaviour, and now my userdata is stored... But I don't really like this solution... Any idea ?

Comment: Hmm I'm editing this answer again : when I use Safari, I don't have the problem, I only encounter it when I'm using Chrome.